# Can't create sqlite database on Windows XP with Django Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, sqlite

I need to create an SQLite database with Django and Python 2.7.

However, when I run "python manage.py syncdb", I receive:

```
unable to open database file
```

Here is a fragment of settings.py file:

```
import os

MANAGERS = ADMINS
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',     
    'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'db'),....
```

I have read several books and tutorials, but can't make a database on Windows.

Comment: try to insert the full db path by hand, aka `DATABASE_NAME = r'C:\djangoapps\myproject\myprojectapp\blog.db'` and please let us know if it works

Answer (score 0):

change
'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'db'),
to
'NAME': 'database.db',